# prove that $2^{1/3}$ cannot be the root of a second degree polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: polynomials, roots, irrational-numbers

I'm trying to prove that $x=2^{1/3}$ cannot be the root of a non-zero second degree polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

I would see how to do it if I knew that either $a$, $b$, or $c$ is $0$, using a similar technique used to show that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational for instance, but here I tried to write $ax^2+bx+c=0$, and to square / cube this expression by moving terms around, but I cant find a way to do it, I always find myself with $x$, $x^2$ and a rational number at the end.

Comment: are you familiar with Eisenstein's criterion for irreducibility?

Comment: You can assume $a=1.$ If $x^2+bx+c=0$ and $x^3=2,$ then $$x^3+bx^2+cx=0=2+bx^2+cx=2+b(-bx-c)+cx=(c-b^2)x+2-bc.$$ So either $c-b^2=2-bc=0,$ or $\sqrt[3]2$ is rational. Show there is no rational $b,c$ so that $c-b^2=2-bc=0.$